# null value in column after migration on different git branch

Tags: django

My model:

```
class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(...)
    description = models.CharField(...)
```

I run `manage.py makemigrations` and `manage.py migrate`

Then I switched to another git branch where `description` field doesn't exist yet but when I try to create new `Item` object I see:

> null value in column "description" violates not-null constrain

What is the best way to fix that?

Comment: model fields reflect database label as you migrate this. switching branch doesn't mater

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your database has a column which is not in your new branch.

So, either drop that column from your database, or create a new DB.

One more option is to go back to the previous branch, make the `description` nullable by updating its definition to:

```
description = models.CharField(null=True...)
```

and then run the `makemigrations` and `migrate` commands.